# Alternative way to orderby grouped product child since filter `woocommerce_grouped_children_args` was removed from WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Wordpress Woocommerce I have created a grouped product, with lots of sub products (children) in it. I tried searching everywhere, but I can not find a working solution how to orderby them by either SKU or product name. It seems that it's orderby is generated by "Menu Order" only. Although as I have 30+ sub products in these multiple grouped products, it would be extremely time wasting to order them by Menu Order value.

I tried the following code, but it seems that it worked in WC 2.5, but not 3.0+ .

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', 
'so_22661392_grouped_children_args' );

function so_22661392_grouped_children_args( $args ){

 $args['meta_key'] = 'sku';
 $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
 $args['order'] = 'ASC'; 
 return $args;

 }
```

I also searched Google for explanations but could not find any. I tried to clear transients, this doesn't work as well:

```
  WooCommerce>System Status>Tools>Clear Transients
```

The grouped product can be seen on https://plastmet.ee/uus/toode/umartoru-kork-zzo-pealekaiv/ . The html table should match the children below, but it does not. SKU for children is "563/9005", "567/9005" etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That filter was removed from 3.0 and not documented. Open up an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues

Comment: I posted something, you should too: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/7021#issuecomment-309538320 Open a new ticket

Comment: any ways of adding this orderby filter to the code meanwhile ??

Comment: No, the filter is gone, so you would have to write your own function as far as I can tell. I would post to the github repo to see what the response is. They are usually helpful in pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I added a bounty and changed the title.

Answer (score 3):

*Hopefully I understand the problem correctly:*

If we have overriden the template file `single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php`, then we could use e.g.:

```
if( $grouped_products )
    usort( $grouped_products, 'wc_products_array_orderby_title' );
```

to sort the grouped products by *title*, instead of the default *menu* ordering.

We could also unregister:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

with a custom callback instead.

As a last resort one could override the `woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart()` function, e.g. within a plugin, to change the menu ordering.

It's defined as:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart' ) ) {

   function woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart() {
       global $product;

       $products = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product->get_children() ) );

       if ( $products ) {
            usort( $products, 'wc_products_array_orderby_menu_order' );

       wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php', array(
           'grouped_product'    => $product,
           'grouped_products'   => $products,
           'quantites_required' => false,
       ) );
    }
  }
}
```

where one could e.g. use `wc_products_array_orderby_title` instead.

Comment: Thank you. This filter that was removed is detailed here when it was added to WooCommerce and then it was undocumented and removed with no peep on how to replace it. Grouped products is a main product with child products on the product single page. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/8820

Comment: I guess a proper way is to use a deprecation notice for developers, e.g. [`apply_filters_deprecated`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters_deprecated/). Are you looking for ways to order the the `$grouped_products` array? I did look into the dynamic `woocommerce_product_get_children` filter (that I spotted deep inside a class with the `get_prop()` method ;-) but it's only applied before the `wc_products_array_orderby_menu_order` ordering of `$grouped_products`. @Christina

Comment: Contact the devs if there is no documentation on this. They answer in a very timely manner.

Comment: Thank for this! Question does anybody know how to order_by on a meta_data custom field?

Comment: Not sure with current version, I would have to refresh myself on this quite a bit to be able to answer that   @sandermander

Comment: @birgire Thanks for the comment. I'm also trying to figuring it out. Let's share when one of us finds out! :-)